# How to display wordpress taxonomy categories in random order on every page refresh

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I need to display wordpress taxonomy categories in random order on every page refresh. I tried the following

```
function get_terms_dropdown($taxonomies, $args){
                            $myterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
                            function shuffle_assoc($list) { 
                                if (!is_array($list)) 
                                   return $list; 

                                $keys = array_keys($list); 
                                shuffle($keys); 
                                $random = array(); 
                                foreach ($keys as $key) { 
                                  $random[$key] = $list[$key]; 
                                }
                                return $random; 
                            } 
                            $outputmain ="<ul class='services_cat'>";
                            $output = array_slice(shuffle_assoc($myterms), 0, 11);
                            foreach($output as $term){
                                    $root_url = get_bloginfo('url');
                                    $term_taxonomy=$term->taxonomy;
                                    $term_slug=$term->slug;
                                    $term_name =$term->name;
                                    $term_desc = $term->description;
                                    $termdesc = get_field('homepage_desciption', $term);
                                    $link = $root_url.'/?'.$term_taxonomy.'='.$term_slug;
                                    $outputmain .="<li><a class='servicecatname'>".$term_name."</a><div class='termdesc'>".$termdesc."</div></li>";
                            }
                            $outputmain .="</ul>";

                    return $outputmain;
                    }
                $taxonomies = array('services-category');
                $args = array('orderby' => 'rand', 'number' => '4','hide_empty'=>false);
                echo get_terms_dropdown($taxonomies, $args);
```

With my code it displays in random order but ONLY the first 4 categories being getted, the rest is ignored.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're ordering by random, then ordering then by ascending. You tried removing this?

Comment: Yes i tried @GavinThomas and no luck

Comment: I updated my question code @GavinThomas . Seems i got soemthing but not exactly

Comment: Your issue is the number argument `'number' => '4'` in `$args` Array, As your code, you are getting only *4 terms* and shuffling them around. as codex [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) `number' argument : _Maximum number of terms to return_

Comment: Yes i underdstand @ShadyAlset . Any idea how i can solve this?

Comment: @AnahitDEV Refer to my answer, i hope it works..

Answer (score 0):

***I suggest to try this:***

1. Retrieve all the terms from your `taxonomy`.
2. Shuffle that returned array randomly with the php function
   `shuffle()`.
3. Pass that through a `foreach loop`.
4. Create a new array and then use `array_slice` to to get the first 4
   entries (as you want in your example).

***Like this rough idea:***

```
$all = get_terms( 'category' );     // Retrieve all the terms.

shuffle( $all );                    // Shuffle that returned array randomly.

$term_names = [];                   // Create a new array.

foreach ( $all as $cat )            // Pass that through a foreach loop.

$term_names[] = $cat->name;         // Fill the new array.

$output = array_slice( $q, 0, 5 );  // get the first 4 entries.

foreach ( $output as $key=>$value ) // Show values !
    echo '<p>' . $value . '</p>';
```

*I hope it works for you, thanks !*